# Change base URL of pages created by certain users

Tags: pages, redirect, author

Currently on wordpress all pages are created under the base URL (example.com/{PAGE}). Currently I am aware you can change the permalink of posts to **example.com/{author}/{POST}** but can this also be done for pages?

On my site I have a main user ‘*admin*’ using id ‘*1*’ and user profiles set as **example.com/members/{author}**

If possible I’d like all pages created by 'admin' to be set as **example.com/{PAGE}**
With pages created by other users set to **example.com/members/{author}/{PAGE}**

The only code i have in place in regards to permalinks is included below incase this will cause any issues.

```
function change_author_permalinks() {

    global $wp_rewrite;

    // Change the value of the author permalink base to whatever you want here
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'members';

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');
```